# Can docplex (module for Constraint Programming optimizer CPLEX for Python) read .lp or .mps file?

Tags: cplex, python, constraint-programming

I want to solve a problem with `docplex.cp` (module for Constraint Programming optimizer CPLEX for Python), and the problem is available in `.lp` or `.mps` formats. But I did not find the attribute for reading a file in it.

For the CPLEX itself, utilizing the `cplex` module it can be done as following:

```
import cplex

Model = cplex.Cplex("MyProblem.lp")
Model.solve()
```

But for the `docplex` module I tried to use `import_model` as following:

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

m = CpoModel()
Model = CpoModel.import_model(m,"MyProblem.lp")
Model.solve()
```

But it is not working as `import_model` only supports `.cpo`  and `.fzn` formats.

Comment: have you tried using other functions from docplex? Like the `docplex.mp`? Maybe this helps: https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html

Comment: And in the "next topic" section of the link above that @JakobS shared you can find [`model_reader` module](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model_reader.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I need to solve with the Constraint Programming optimizer, so I guess "docplex.cp" is the right module. Am I right that "docplex.mp" is equivalent to using "cplex" module?

Comment: That is right you need to use "DOcplex.cp" but more information can be found in the link: "https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/cp/index.html"

Comment: @OguzToragay Yeah, and there is no function to read `.lp` or `.mps` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for using docplex.
Currently, docplex.cp can import only .cpo and .mzn files. Maybe this could be extended in the next future.